# Python Function Won't End

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file of (county, state, year) tuples called `ctyear.csv`. For each tuple, I need the number of fast food places and grocery stores (`num_ff` and `num_groc`) by year, county and state. This information is kept in Census Data files named by year (so `cbp96co.csv'` refers to data in  1996) in the following format:

```
state, year, county, industry_code, number_of_establishments
'1', '1996', '55030', '30', '20'
'1', '1996', '55404', '31', '13' 
'14', '1996' , '23', '5411', '24'
```

The industry codes for fast food and groceries - the industries that I'm interested in getting information about - differ by year. The helper function `whichcode()` - not included in this below code - returns the industry codes relevant to a given year.

Given a year, open file handles `rawff` , `rawgroc`, `fferrors`, and `grocerrors`, the following function looks up the number of grocery and fastfood restaurants (given by the appropriate industry codes for that year) for each (county, state, year) tuple in `ctyear` and writes it to the CSV file handles mentioned above.

This function prints the correct results; in this sense, it works. It extracts the right data. However, it won't end. When I call it, the function will not terminate even after printing the last line. When I call this function over a single year in Terminal, after printing the last line of the function, Terminal simply shows a flashing cursor for the next few hours - it doesn't seem to stop. What could be going wrong?

```
def extractCBPdata(year, rawff, rawgroc, fferrors, grocerrors): 
   # Initialize file name, get the set of codes we're interested in extracting for this year using whichcode()
    fname = "cbp"+str(year)+"co.txt"
    info = whichcode(year)
    codename = info['codename']
    groccode = info['groccode']
    ffcode = info['ffcode']
    cbpind = {} 
   # Index data file by (state, county, year, code)
    for line in csv.DictReader(open(fname, 'rb')): 
        cbpind[(int(line['fipstate']), int(line['fipscty']), getyear(year), line[codename])] = line
   # Read a list of tuples of (state, county, year) that we want information about
    ctyear = csv.DictReader(open('ctyear.csv', 'r')) 
   # For every (state, county, year) tuple in the above file, get info from the cbpind for relevant codes
    for c in ctyear:  
        if c['year'] == getyear(year): 
            fipstate = int(c['fipstate']) 
            fipscty = int(c['fipscty']) 
            for fc in ffcode: 
               if (fipstate, fipscty, getyear(year), fc) in cbpind: 
                      line1 = cbpind[(fipstate, fipscty, getyear(year), fc)] 
                      st = line1['fipstate'] 
                      cty = line1['fipscty']
                      num_ff = line1['est'] 
                      row_titles = ['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'codename', 'code', 'year', 'num_ff']
                      row = [st, cty, codename, fc, getyear(year), num_ff] 
                      rawff.writerow(dict(zip(row_titles, row)))
               else: 
                      fferrors.writerow(dict(zip(['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'year', 'ffcode'], [fipstate, fipscty, getyear(year), fc])))
            for gc in groccode:         
                if (fipstate, fipscty, getyear(year), gc) in cbpind: 
                      line2 = cbpind[(fipstate, fipscty, getyear(year), gc)]
                      st = line2['fipstate'] 
                      cty = line2['fipscty'] 
                      num_groc = line2['est']
                      row_titles = ['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'codename', 'code', 'year', 'num_groc']
                      row = [st, cty, codename, fc, year, num_groc]
                      rawgroc.writerow(dict(zip(row_titles, row)))
               else: 
                      grocerrors.writerow(dict(zip(['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'year', 'grocode'], [fipstate, fipscty, year, gc])))
    print "Done writing for " + str(year)
    return
```

I implement this function using the following lines:

```
g = ['num_groc', 'fipstate', 'fipscty', 'codename', 'code', 'year']
ff = ['num_ff', 'fipstate', 'fipscty', 'codename', 'code', 'year']
rawff = csv.DictWriter(open('raw_ff' + str(year) + '.csv', 'w'), fieldnames = ff)
rawgroc = csv.DictWriter(open('raw_groc' + str(year) + '.csv', 'w'), fieldnames = g) 
fferrors = csv.DictWriter(open('fferrors' + str(year) + '.csv', 'w'), fieldnames = ['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'year', 'ffcode'])
grocerrors = csv.DictWriter(open('grocerrors' + str(year) + '.csv', 'w'), fieldnames = ['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'year', 'grocode'])
grocerrors.writerow(dict(zip(['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'year', 'grocode'], ['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'year', 'grocode'])))
rawff.writerow(dict(zip(ff,ff)))
rawgroc.writerow(dict(zip(g,g)))
fferrors.writerow(dict(zip(['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'year', 'ffcode'],['fipstate', 'fipscty', 'year', 'ffcode'])))

years = ['96', '97', '98', '99', '00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05']
for y in years: 
    l = extractCBPdata(y)
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Where does the script hang?

Comment: Aside: if you're going to be performing this kind of manipulation on CSV files, I strongly recommend taking a look at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library.

Comment: The script hangs on the last line of the function - the print statement: it prints out "Done wring for 96" but nothing after that.

Comment: And I have not tried a debugger. I'll look into that and the Pandas library, thanks.